# How to implement ng-model binding on this getter/setter scenario?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, getter-setter, angularjs-scope

I have an object exposing 2 properties (say `foo` and `bar`) via getters/setters in the form of `method([value])`, so you can get their value by calling `method()` and you can set their value by calling `method(value)`.

Also, this object keeps `foo` and `bar` synchronized, in the way it makes `bar` always to be 1 greater than `foo`). This means whenever you set the value of `foo`, it internally updates the value of `bar`, and viceversa.

This is the sample implementation:

```
function obj() {
    var foo = 1;
    var bar = 2;

    return {
        foo: function (value) {
            if (value) {
                foo = value;
                bar = foo + 1;
            }
            return foo;
        },
        bar: function (value) {
            if (value) {
                bar = value;
                foo = bar - 1;
            }
            return bar;
        }
    }    
}
```

Now I have two `input` elements, one for each of these properties.

```
// in my controller
$scope.myobj = obj();

<!-- in the HTML -->
<input my-directive ng-model="myobj.foo">
<input my-directive ng-model="myobj.bar">
```

Please remember that `foo` and `bar` are functions, so I write a `$formatter` to get the value by calling the getter; and a `$parser` to set the value by calling the setter, like this:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
               return modelValue(); 
            });

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
               ngModel.$modelValue(viewValue);
               return ngModel.$modelValue;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

You can check the example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TeRxs/) or [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VwueaX?p=preview).

As you can see, the formatter/parser thing works just fine, but the problem is that the `<input>` value of the property that is internally modified (say `bar` if you changed `foo`) **is not updated**.

I can't even grasp why in earth is not working. As you can see in the example, below each input I'm interpolating the same value which seems perfectly updated upon any change. **Why ng-model isn't updating my `<input>` value?**

Comment: `$formatters` run "whenever the model value changes." My guess is that `$modelValue` never changes--it remains a static constant reference to `foo()` or `bar()`. You *call* the function to change an *internal* representation of some data, but the thing that `ngModel` is attached to never changes. The DOM updates because the binding to `foo()` and `bar()`--the *results* of those function calls--*do* update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way you could do it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7HCpSb?p=preview

(It looks a kind of hacky and I do not like my solution very much, though.)

As @Brandon pointed out, you are watching the getter function.
The function evaluation may give different values, but function definition 
never changes in your example, so formatter never fires in your directive.

In my example, I'm watching the `evaluation of the getter function`,
so it fires whenever internal value changes.
I avoided using ngModel as it does not look fit in this way.

in the template:

```
<input my-directive accessor="myobj.foo">
```

in the directive link function:

```
$scope.$watch( $attrs.accessor + '()', function( v ) {
  if ( v ) $element[0].value = v;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I could get a getter/setter scenario to work by coding another directive besides of ng-model for specifying the getter and the setter of a ng-model binding. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21290588/738808

Using the ng-model-getter and ng-model-setter directives described in this question, you would just proceed this way in your html:

```
<input my-directive ng-model="$foo" ng-model-getter="myobj.foo()" ng-model-setter="myobj.foo($value)">
<input my-directive ng-model="$bar" ng-model-getter="myobj.bar()" ng-model-setter="myobj.bar($value)">
```